# Creating a vertical, dynamic table in Javascript with an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

Skip right to the bottom if you'd just like to read the questions. The top lot is just context. Not vital but might help.

While working on  a table in html I realised something. The code was terrible, repetitive and wasteful. Might as we have been manually adding the array.

```
<!-- 
<table border="4px" >
            <caption>
            Pet Table
            </caption>
            <tr> // Images
                <td>
                    <script>
                    display(bat)
                    </script>;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <script>
                    display(goat)
                    </script>               
                </td>
                <td>
                    <script>
                    display(butterfly)
                    </script>   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <script>
                    display(buzzard)
                    </script>   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <script>
                    display(breezie)
                    </script>   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <script>
                    display(turtle)
                    </script>   
                </td>
            </tr >
            <tr> // Names
                <td>
                    name
                </td>
                <td>
                    name
                </td>
                <td>
                    name
                </td>
                <td>
                    name
                </td>
                <td>
                    name
                </td>
                <td>
                    name
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <tr> //Desc
                <td>
                    desc
                </td>
                <td>
                    desc
                </td>
                <td>
                    desc
                </td>
                <td>
                    desc
                </td>
                <td>
                    desc
                </td>
                <td>
                    desc
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <tr> //Food
                <td>
                    food
                </td>
                <td>
                    food
                </td>
                <td>
                    food
                </td>
                <td>
                    food
                </td>
                <td>
                    food
                </td>
                <td>
                    food
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <tr> //button
                <td>
                    button
                </td>
                <td>
                    button
                </td>
                <td>
                    button
                </td>
                <td>
                    button
                </td>
                <td>
                    button
                </td>
                <td>
                    button
                </td>               

        </table>
 -->
```

This lead me to spending the morning theorising and experimenting with creating tables dynamically from javaScript instead.

This was the code I was came up with.

In JavaScript (*Edit added pet array)

```
function pet(species, name, colour, size, food, limb, img) {
    this.species = species; //property of a pet
    this.name = name; //property of a pet
    this.colour = colour; //property of a pet
    this.size = size; //property of a pet
    this.food = food; //property of a pet
    this.limb = limb; //property of a pet
    this.img = img; //property of a pet         
    this.move = move; //a function of a pet defined to the pet      

    var bat = new pet("fruit bat", "bats", "grey", "small", "apples", "wings", "1", move);
    var goat = new pet("goat", "bastard", "off white", "goat-sized", "clothing", "hooves", "2", move);
    var butterfly = new pet("butterfly", "flutterby", "rainbow", "petite", "nectar", "wings", "3", move);
    var buzzard = new pet("buzzard", "Buzz", "molted black and white", "bigish", "carrion", "wings", "4", move);
    var breezie = new pet("pixie", "petty", "blue", "tiny", "souls", "wings", "5", move);
    var turtle = new pet("tortoise", "Tank", "Green", "smoothbacked", "lettuce", "legs", "6", move);

    var len = pet.length;

    function buildTable() {
        document.getElementById("work");
        //i is a counter, f is a flag   
        var f = 0;
        while (f = 0) {
            document.write("<table border='4px'>" + "</br>");
            document.write("<caption>Pets Avaliable</caption>" + "</br>");
            document.write("<tr>" + "</br>");
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                document.write("<td>" + imgArray[i].outerHTML + "</td>" + "</br>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>" + "</br>");
            document.write("<tr>" + "</br>");
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                document.write("<td>" + pet[i].species + "</td> " + "</br>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>" + "</br>");
            document.write("<tr>" + "</br>");
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                document.write("<td>" + pet[i].name + "</td>" + "</br>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>" + "</br>");
            document.write("<tr>" + "</br>");
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                document.write("<td>" + pet[i].colour + "</td> " + "</br>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>" + "</br>");
            document.write("<tr>" + "</br>");
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                document.write("<td>" + pet[i].size + "</td>" + "</br>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>" + "</br>");
            document.write("<tr>" + "</br>");
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                document.write("<td>" + pet[i].food + "</td>" + "</br>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>" + "</br>");
            document.write("</table>" + "</br>");
            f = 1;
        }

    }
    document.getElementById("please");
```

The HTML

```
<button id="please" onclick="buildTable(pet)"> Work you blighter </button>
<p id="work"></p>
```

I just couldn't get it to work. Console was showing no errors yet the button provided no results. After a long while of digging I did manage to come across a  button that worked. (I added `.innerHTML = "The button is working"` to `document.getElementById("work")`in order to test it.) So the button was alright. Therefore the problem must be in the function itself right? Bloody right. I know it's wrong and I'll try again tomorrow using similar codes to these posts
 [Dynamically creating a table in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974710/dynamically-creating-a-table-in-javascript)  /
http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/1/
and
[Create vertical column table based on Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651542/javascript-create-vertical-column-table-based-on-array-of-objects)
I don't mind working towards an answer nor trial and error but what grinds my garters is that I can't figure out what was the problem. It's good to find out how the code works but I'd like to find out why it works  the way it does as well.

**Questions**

1. Why can't the console and debugger find any errors yet the page is obviously not working.
2. How would I label these kinds of problems in the future?What was at fault? The button? The function? Both? Neither? Myself?
3. I'm planning to make the table in a vertical column format instead of horizontal. Would this be problematic to do? (I'm thinking a few more for loops should do the trick without a fuss)
4. I'd like to use a pre-constructed array as a source for data(e.g `pet[i].size` but would this work or would it be better to dis-assemble the array into variables in the function?
5. if I do need to make variables for all the data would I be able to recycle or reuse a variable if it's inside one of the loops?
6. In http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/1/  why is  `"tbdy"` a child of tab or is `appendChild` used to assign "`tbdy"`  to `tab`?

I now know how to go about fixing the dynamic table but I don't know what specifically was wrong in the first place. Please share your knowledge with us.

Comment: I see you specifying it in the onclick, but what is pet? I also see it's length being checked before the function definition, but I don't see a definition for pet anywhere. Can you add that?

Comment: @Daved It is the array where I'm drawing data from. I've added it to the Javascript section.

Comment: Add closing `}` to `pet` function in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't the console and debugger find any errors yet the page is obviously not working.

There are no errors in code, it just doesn't make, what you'd like it to do.

> How would I label these kinds of problems in the future?What was at fault? The button? The function? Both? Neither? Myself?

There were a few critical errors, hard to point out one deciding.

> I'm planning to make the table in a vertical column format instead of horizontal. Would this be problematic to do? (I'm thinking a few more for loops should do the trick without a fuss)

Making it horizontal may be even easier.

> I'd like to use a pre-constructed array as a source for data(e.g pet[i].size but would this work or would it be better to dis-assemble the array into variables in the function?

It is good idea to make a variable for `pet[i]`, if you are going to use it a few times. If you meant making separate tables for size, name etc. - no, there is no need for that.

> if I do need to make variables for all the data would I be able to recycle or reuse a variable if it's inside one of the loops?

I'm not sure what do you mean, but probably answer is yes. In javascript variables are local to function, and all loops, ifs etc. inside one function use the same variables.

> In http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/1/ why is "tbdy" a child of tab or is appendChild used to assign "tbdy" to tab?

`tbdy` is a child of table element `tab`, which means that it is inside it.

#### Ok, now problems with your code:

1. Code inside `while` never executes. You have assignment `f=0` instead of equality check `f==0` (or better `f===0`) in condition. `f=0` has value `0`, so it is false. And also, there is no need for loop at all, if you want it to execute exactly once.
2. `document.write` is not going to work sensibly while called from `onclick`. `document.write` does make sense almost exclusively when called directly in `<script>` tag, and should be avoided in general.
3. Your calls to `document.getElementById` just return object which is then forgotten - they don't have any effect.
4. You call `buildTable` with argument `pet`, but `buildTable` does not take any arguments (it is not a big problem now, because `pet` seems to be global variable, but it may be misleading).
5. You don't declare `i` as local variable, so it is global. It will work, but in very bug-prone manner.
6. Putting `<br>` tag inside `<table>` does make no sense and is incorrect, and `</br>` (as you write it) [isn't even legal tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).
   You might want to put newline character (`\n`) there, but it is not needed, you don't have to separate html tags.
7. Your code is very repetitive, with lots of almost identical `for` loops.
8. Indent your code, it will make it much nicer to read.

#### Possible solutions using approach similar to yours (building html piece by piece from strings):

(before using (not recommended), read carefully notes below)

```
var pet = [
    {
        species: 'species1',
        name: 'name1',
        colour: 'colour1',
        size: 'size1',
    },
    {
        species: 'species2',
        name: 'name2',
        colour: 'colour2',
        size: 'size2',
    },
];
    
function makeTr(pet, attrName) {
    var html = '',
        i;
    
    html += "<tr>";
    for (i = 0; i < pet.length; ++i) {
        html += "<td>" + pet[i][attrName] + "</td>";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
    return html;
}

function buildTable(pet) {
    var html='';
    
    html += "<table border='4px'>";
    html += "<caption>Pets Avaliable</caption>";
    
    html += makeTr(pet, "species");
    html += makeTr(pet, "name");
    html += makeTr(pet, "colour");
    html += makeTr(pet, "size");
    
    html += "</table>"

    document.getElementById("work").innerHTML = html;
}
```

[(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5oq7o0vn/2/)

Note, that it is far from being the best solution, and putting html manually
may be considered bad by principle (althought it may be a bit faster and
could be justified in some cases). In general, creating html tag with
`document.createElement` seems cleaner and less error-prone way to do that.
Specifically, *code above may possibly be subject to XSS attack*, because values put into html are not sanitized. Paul's solution is not affected by this problem - note the use of `text()` method, which escapes html code.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. 'f=0' was a silly mistake I admit.  Using == and === takes some getting use to but I'll remember to use them now.  Thank you for introducing me to attrName, It's not in the provided workbook here at college but it's the exact thing I was looking for. It'll help keep the code nice and compact.  I'm not concerned with security of the program just yet. It's just a school project but thank you for the warning.  After testing your code (Just testing, I've not intention of plagiarizing yours.) I've discovered that I misunderstood how Arrays work. I'll see to that.

Comment: The way arrays and objects work in JS is quite specific. It is worthy to point out that `foo["name"]` and `foo.name` have *exactly* the same meaning. The only real difference is that former syntax allows using variable as name of attribute, and using attribute names which are not correct identifiers (e.g. containing spaces or dashes), while the latter is a bit shorter and prettier.

Comment: I went and added all those pet variables to an array by adding `var petArray = ["bat","goat","butterfly","buzzard","breezie","turtle"]; `After adjusting your code I tried to test again but sadly it still sees `petArray[i]` as undefined. **edit** Sorry I'm lying What it does do is give me a table full of `undefined`. The `petArray[1] is undefined` error is a different matter relating to something else.

Comment: It is hard to say something about your problem without an actual code. Please make sure, that you don't confuse local variables/arguments with global ones - that may be a problem - and that the order of execution is proper.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in your code.

1. `while(f=0){` will always evaluate to 0, and hence false.  You probably wanted `while(f === 0) {` (yes, triple `===`).  This is causing the "I don't see anything in the console" problem, because the code is actually (as you suspected) working albeit not as you expect.
2. Every one of your loops has `for(i = 0; i <= len; i++)`, where `var len = pet.length;`  You will get an index out of bounds with this, you would want to change to `for(i = 0; i < len; i++)`.

And finally:

3. You probably don't want to use document.write.  The first document.write call will clear the document and replace it with your table.  You would be better off with document.createElement and friends to do DOM manipulation (per the jsfiddles you posted).  If you go this route, you would be much better off using a library like jQuery, where you could end up with something like this:

```js
//
// Dummy data to make the sample work.
//
var imgArray = [
 {outerHTML: '1.jpg'}
, {outerHTML: '2.jpg'}
, {outerHTML: '3.jpg'}
, {outerHTML: '4.jpg'}
];

var pet = [
 {species: 'species1', name: 'name1', colour: 'colour1', size: 'size1', food: 'food1'}
, {species: 'species2', name: 'name2', colour: 'colour2', size: 'size2', food: 'food2'}
, {species: 'species3', name: 'name3', colour: 'colour3', size: 'size3', food: 'food3'}
, {species: 'species4', name: 'name4', colour: 'colour4', size: 'size4', food: 'food4'}
];

var attributes = $.map(pet[0], function(n, v) { return v; });

function generateTable(id) {
    var $table = $(id);
    var $tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
        
    $table.append($tbody);
        
    // the images
    var $tr = $('<tr />');
    $.each(imgArray, function (ignored, image) {
        $tr.append($('<td />').html(image.outerHTML));
    });
    $tbody.append($tr);
        
    $.each(attributes, function (ignored, attribute) {
        $tr = $('<tr />');
        $.each(pet, function (i, p) {
            // i == index, p == pet[i]
            $tr.append($('<td />').text(p[attribute]));
        });
        $tbody.append($tr);
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('#generateTable').click(function () {
        generateTable('#tableHere');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="generateTable">Generate table</button>
<div id="tableHere"></div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used the '<=' instead of '< 'because I was concerned that the loop may skip the last object in the array. Just me miss reading the code is all, I've fixed it and won't repeat that mistake .  I've every intention of learning to use jQuery some time in the future but for now I'd like to learn the vanilla Javascript first. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @HugovanDyk I agree that learning vanilla is valuable - because you'll soon bump into problems between browsers where browsers implement interfaces to the DOM in slightly different ways.  It's at this point that you'll probably want to use something like jQuery to handle the differences between browsers because you understand _why_ to use it, rather than using it just to use it.  :-)